# Write to a range of perl array

Tags: perl

I have a 32-bit array, @data
Want to write zeros for [16] to [31]
Are there shorter methods to do this?

`splice(@data,16,16,(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0))`

Comment: Do you mean a 32 element array?

Comment: @Shawn An array of 32 elements which are bits.

Comment: btw, those parens are superfluous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```perl
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
```

can be written as

```perl
( 0 ) x 16
```

So,

```perl
splice( @data, 16, 16, ( 0 ) x 16 );
```

---

That said, it's weird to use an array for bits. We'd normally use a number.

To keep only the least significant 16 bits, we'd use

```perl
$data &= 0xFFFF;
```

To keep only the most significant 16 bits of 32, we'd use

```perl
$data &= 0xFFFF0000;
```

or

```perl
$data &= ~0xFFFF;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use an [array slice](https://perldoc.perl.org/perldata#Slices) instead of `splice` to assign a list to a range of indices all at once:

```perl
@data[16..31] = (0) x 16;
```